# stretch a row to fit the data in jasper reports using iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I use iReport 2.0.5 to generate jrxml file and use the same in my java web propject, I have used all the flags to stretch to fit the data, but it doesn't work

The example:

```xml
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None" hyperlinkTarget="Self" > 
    <reportElement style="dNew" mode="Opaque" x="55" y="0" width="55" height="19" key="value-1" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" positionType="Float" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/> 
    <box></box> 
    <textElement> 
        <font/> 
    </textElement> 
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{value1}]]></textFieldExpression> 
</textField>
```

Comment: Ask at JasperForge, too. http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport

Answer (score 1):

It should be able to stretch down based on the band.

If it is a TextField you can set the option "Stretch with Overflow" AFAIK straight StaticTexts will not overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following two properties in your reportElement tag.

```
name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"
name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="false"
```